# Is 有方 an abbreviation of 有方法？

Tags: meaning

I hadn't heard 有方 before. I was surprised to find it means 'competent'.

A basic meaning of '方' is 'square'.

Is this '方' actually 方法，方式？ Could I change '方' for '方式' in '他领导有方'?

Comment: Yes you are right, you pretty much answered yourself

Answer (score 4):

Yes [方](http://www.zdic.net/z/1b/xs/65B9.htm) means `方法` (method) here, and [有方](http://www.zdic.net/c/9/8d/157744.htm) means `(do something) with the proper method/in the right way`, i.e. `competent`.

> [with the proper method]∶得法
>   领导有方